# Angular2: Visibility of Input-properties

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component parent that calls another component child with an input-property.

The property is available in the childs template but not in the constructor or OnInit. Thats normal behaviour or am I doing something wrong?

**parent.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: "parent",
  template: `<child [name]="'foobar'"></child>`
})

export class ParentComponent
{
}
```

**child.component.ts**

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: "child",
  template: "name={{ name }}"
})

export class ChildComponent
{
  @Input () name:string="init";

  constructor ()
  {
    console.log ("constr: " + name);
  }

  ngOnInit ()
  {
    console.log ("oninit: " + name);
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

- Corrected my sample and put @Input inside the class.
- Changed my sample to real code.
  The template shows "foobar", the console shows an empty string.

Comment: It is not necessarily set immediately, if you want access to the value implement OnChanges. Also note you can just do `name=“test”` for a string value.

Comment: And the name, decorated with the Input(), must be inside the class. Why don't you post a complete, real, minimal example instead of some pseudo-code. We could reproduce the problem, rather than having to guess what could be the problem.

Comment: Can't reproduce, after changing `name` to `this.name` (but again, is it because this bug is in your code and you ignored the TypeScript errors, or because what you posted is pseudo-code?) http://plnkr.co/edit/8V86k9JQ5ZyDnZCCHgDt?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
console.log ("oninit: " + name);
```

to

```
console.log ("oninit: " + this.name);
```

Comment: Okay, looks like I had bad luck. I get a compiler.error for any property where I forgot the "this." (what I did and what was the reason it was without values in onInit) BUT NOT for a property named "name"... Is that sort of reserved name for a property or what??

Comment: lib.es6.d.ts defines `declare const name: never;`. I have no idea what this global constant is, though.